# Sending a string using ajax and express.js to the server and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I need to send a string, 'resultString', from the client to the server in order for it to send to MongoDB and results returned.
This js file gets values from checkboxes and creates the result string

client

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (result.length > 0) {
      var resultString = "";
      result.each(function() {
        resultString += $(this).val() + " ";
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: '/recipe',
        data: resultString,
        success: function(data) {
          //DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("No checkbox checked");
    }
  });
});
```

server

```
router.get('/recipe', function(req, res, next) {
  Recipe.find({
    $text: {
      $search: req.resultString
    }
  }, {
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  }, function(err, recipe) {

    res.json(recipe);

  }).sort({
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  });
});
```

I tried receiving by putting req.resultString but this didn't work. This search method works as if i was to put a search term instead of req.resultString it would return database reults to the /recipe page but i want 'resultString' to be here. Thanks

Comment: req.resultstring veya req.body.resultstringAnd there are al ot of mistakes.

Comment: For example you can get recipe after sort:)

Comment: @ŞükranEken Sorry what do you mean by the 2nd comment?

Comment: try to use `body parser`

Comment: Firstly use body parser.And like this**req.body.resultstring**And use sort method before `function(err,recipe)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need body-parser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then use the search variable like this:

```
router.get('/recipe', function(req, res) {
     var qs = {};
     qs.searchCriteria= req.body.resultString;
     Recipe.find(qs, function(err, data){
        //data should be the search result
        console.log(data);
  })
})
```

*searchCriteria* should be your search property in DB like, name, id or what column you search for, is something like: `SELECT * FROM wallpapers WHERE searchCriteria IS yourSearchString`

Comment: add text search:)